# Android contact info update with intent?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I can create new contact with Intent by passing info as extra data with putExtra, is it possible to create Intent with info and if contact is already in phonebook it will be update with new info?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually you can use intents to create new contacts with ContactsContract and it's not deprecated.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html

example that works for me:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
i.putExtra(Insert.NAME, "TESTTEST");
i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, "209384");
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Intents to create new contacts is deprecated since Android 2.0. Use [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).

Here are the [docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) and an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336019/new-contacts-created-using-contactscontract-do-not-appear-in-contacts-app).

Comment: First tnx for help, but this need to be operational for Android 1.6, so ContactsContract doesn't help.