# Created contacts not showing up on HTC Evo

Tags: android, contactscontract, android-contacts

I'm writing a program that imports our contacts into the Contacts db on the phone so they show up in the Contacts app, are available for caller id to draw from, etc. I've got it working the way we want on the emulator and the Motorola Droid. When I go to Menu --> View, I can see our application with a check box next to it, and when it's checked, our contacts show up fine.

However, when I try the same thing on the HTC Evo, the contacts don't show up in People, and I don't have our application listed in the View menu. The contacts show up when I do a search within People, and when the contact calls the phone, their contact info shows up fine.

The contacts I'm testing our application with aren't in the phone already ;-) They're special test cases with unique names; that's how I'm able to determine they are actually coming from our app.

I sort of get the feeling this is a HTC Sense issue, but I don't have a way to confirm that right now. If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with an app that does contact sync using the Android 2.x API.  The contacts I've added don't appear in the Sense contacts app or the Motoblur contacts app.  They appear in the emulator's default (ie Google) contacts app, though.

I know that the problem with motoblur is that (per moto's website) the blur contacts API is based off of the old Contacts API found in Android 1.x, and not the new 2.x ContactsContract API.  It's possible that HTC does the same, though I've not been able to find any confirmation of that despite a little bit of googling.

Comment: No kidding?? That's good to know about motoblur. I think you're dead on about HTC as well :-/ Manufacturer customization of the OS is a strong feature, but also a huge weakness. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: One workaround is to click the + sign on the home screen, choose Folder, then All People

Comment: Just to update, the Contacts 2.x API works on MOTOBLUR phones running Gingerbread (Android 2.3) or higher.  My Droid X is running Moto's new Gingerbread, and I'm quite pleased that this now works.