# Create a pre filled contact with the standard Activity

Tags: android

In my app i'm trying to create a Contact by calling the standard Create/Edit contact Activity.

I've found how to make it work but not exactly the way I like.

For now I manage to call the standard create contact activity with the following intent extra:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, Uri.parse(String.format("tel: %s", data.getPhone())));
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.EXTRA_FORCE_CREATE, true);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, data.getName());
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, org.getPhone());
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, org.getAddress() + " " + org.getZipCode());
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, org.getEmail());
startActivity(i);
```

All the data is filled properly except the address field as you can see in the following picture: http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/1073/capturevvm.png

I'd like to specify each part of the address in the separate field. Is there a way to do it with an Intent?

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, "toto");
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, "paris");
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
contactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "2 rue de Romme, 75000 Paris");
contactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the contact using the technique at [New contacts created using ContactsContract do not appear in Contacts app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336019/new-contacts-created-using-contactscontract-do-not-appear-in-contacts-app)

Then show it using your technique.